# Query / map-reduce in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We are playing around with mongodb, but are having som troubles with a query.

We have made a powershell script that fetches drive-info from our servers and saves it in mongodb.

Our model:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("514332334a62a9209c22c866"),
  "FreeSpace" : NumberLong("9439911936"),
  "Name" : "C",
  "TotalSize" : NumberLong("128033222656"),
  "Server" : "pcws24",
  "Tidspunkt" : ISODate("2013-03-15T14:37:39.457Z")
}
```

Edit: I have changed the datamodel to this. It should simplify the query.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("514c2ee94a62a914e0bbe954"),
  "Server" : "pcws24",
  "Tidspunkt" : ISODate("2013-03-22T10:14:01.4Z"),
  "Drev" : [{
      "DriveLetter" : "C",
      "VolumeLabel" : "",
      "FreeSpace" : NumberLong("6715068416"),
      "TotalSize" : NumberLong("128033222656")
    }, {
      "DriveLetter" : "D",
      "VolumeLabel" : "Data",
      "FreeSpace" : NumberLong("80200286208"),
      "TotalSize" : NumberLong("159891058688")
    }]
}
```

We have the following use case scenarios.

- Get the latest status for each drive on each server.
- Get status for the last 24 hours for each drive on each server.
- Get status for the last week for each drive on each server.
  etc.

The model is created from the Get-Drive cmdlet.

How do we accomplish this? Can it be done with a query or should we use map/reduce?

Comment: What is the "status" in this case?  Could you provide perhaps an example of what you would like to see from the query results?  I am unsure what the meaning of the fields are, could you clarify?  Are the documents continually being pulled into mongodb, or are they created once and then continually updated?  Sorry for all the questions, but I am not sure how to help you without understanding the situation more completely

Comment: Status is one document for each drive on each server. So the latest use case would show server 1 drive c 10 gb free, drive d 100 gb free, server 2 drive c 15 gb etc.

Comment: Status is one document for each drive on each server. So the latest use case would show server 1 drive c 10 gb free, drive d 100 gb free, server 2 drive c 15 gb etc. 24 hour is all the documents from the last 24 hours. So we Can see how disk space usage is progressing. The server script runs every hour and adds new documents.

Comment: One last question: when you say each, do you mean that you want to get back the results for all the servers from a single query?  Or are you wanting to be able to specify the server/disk that you would like to get info on?  Getting info from a single server/disk is a fairly simple query, however it seems to me that getting info on all of them from a single query is a more complex operation that will probably use mongodb's aggregation framework.

Comment: If I could get results for each server in one query that would be perfect. I could make the presentation side more dynamic. It wouldn't need to know the server names.